# What are the features that Azure VM based SQL server supports and the managed instance doesn't support?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm deciding on whether to install SQL server on azure VM versus configuring a managed instance.

I understand that the following features are not supported by managed instance:

```
SSIS
SSAS
SSRS
Manual patching
Full OS control
```

Is there anything else that managed instance doesn't support that sql server on azure vm will support? For example:

```
Transactional replication
Always On availability groups
Log shipping
MDS
DQS
```

Answer (score 5):

You can read about the differences and similarities in [Feature comparison of Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance and SQL Server on a VM](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/feature-comparison-of-azure-sql-database-azure-sql-managed/ba-p/3154789) as there's too many to list out, and some are very granular differences. You may also find additional information in [T-SQL differences between SQL Server & Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server), as mentioned per Tibor Karaszi.

For example, both have High Availability via AlwaysOn Availability Groups, but you have less control over them in an Azure SQL Managed Instance, which tries to automate the High Availability for you.

Transactional Replication also appears to be a feature available in both cases, but per those docs, is still in Public Preview for a Managed Instance. Merge Replication, Peer-to-Peer Replication, and Updatable Subscriptions are **not** available in a Managed Instance. For further information on limitations of Replication in a Managed Instance please see [Transactional replication with Azure SQL Managed Instance (Preview)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-sql/managed-instance/replication-transactional-overview.md)